# In if condition i am getting date difference (-1) if i enter current date. It should be zero

Tags: oracle-adf

```
import oracle.jbo.domain.Date;

public Date getCurrentDateTime() {
        return new Date(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

public void Method(){
        eventstartDate = (oracle.jbo.domain.Timestamp)this.bndevtfromdate.getValue();
        eventendDate = (oracle.jbo.domain.Timestamp)this.bndevttodate.getValue();
        if (eventstartDate.compareTo(getCurrentDateTime()) < 0) {       
                showmessage("Start Date cannot be less than Today's Date", "I");
        }
}
```

i am making an event circular in which no one can enter date before today's date to make an entry of event. event start date and event end date are two variables used defined as class variables of timestamp.

Comment: Did you debug and see what are the exact values assigned to `eventStartDate` and `getCurrentTime` ? Can you share them here too ?

Comment: i am using getCurrentDatetime() function to save date for table columns "created Date"  and "Modified date" and the values getting into the data base are correct. It only gives me wrong in CompareTo condition.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  in  getCurrentDateTime()  --> System.currentTimeMillis() 1490760724129 long

Comment: and in "if" condition i am getting (-1)

Comment: What you are sharing is the number of milliseconds? Can you share the actual DateTime values which are being compared?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  by entering today's date in eventstartdate i am getting data of byte[7] with values [0]-> 120-'x' , [1]->117-'u' , [2]->3-" , [3]->29-''' and in 4 to 6  all  1  with  '   '.

Comment: and in  getcurrentdatetime()  upto byte[3]  its same and in byte [4] to [6] i am getting 11-'' , 12-'' and 40-'('

Comment: Is it valid to compare oracle Timestamp with regular Java Date object? I think they should be same type.